# Did any Ethiopian leaders help the Italians?

Tags: colonization, africa, italy, ethiopia

Around the two Italo-Ethiopian wars, did any Ethiopian leaders side with the Italians?

By "around", I mean anywhere from about 1890 to 1936.

By "leaders", I mean noblemen, military officers, popular leaders, government officials, etc.

Comment: Interesting question. I would be quite astonished if some notable Ethiopians with local power did not assist the Italians -- from a purely pragmatic viewpoint. That is, they envisioned an Italian win, and thought it advantageous to be on the winning side.

Comment: @Noldorin, that's where I'm at.  I expect it did happen, but I have no evidence to back up that expectation.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't really offering info. Curious to hear of a real answer here too...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Haile Selasse Gugsa with Mussolini, 1937, Rome]

[Haile Selassie Gugsa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haile_Selassie_Gugsa) (second from right), a military commander and governor of Eastern Tigray, turned coat just a week into the invasion. After the war he was sentenced to death (commuted to life imprisonment and later house arrest.)